# How to use the `resource_key ` and `resources_key ` in openstacksdk Resource?

Tags: openstack

How to use the `resource_key` and `resources_key` in openstacksdk Resource?

In the `openstack/compute/v2/Image`:

```
class Image(resource2.Resource, metadata.MetadataMixin):
    resource_key = 'image'
    resources_key = 'images'
    base_path = '/images'
    service = compute_service.ComputeService()

    # capabilities
    allow_get = True
    allow_delete = True
    allow_list = True
```

There are `resource_key`,`resources_key`and `base_path`.
is this representative the resource path like rest_framework?

[image]

How to use the `resource_key`, `resources_key` and `base_path` in openstacksdk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the resource_key and resources_key are for internal interactions with backend services (e.g. nova compute, cinder storage). Users are not supposed to use them directly.

However, if you are planning to help out on improving openstacksdk, you will need to understand that resources_key is a component for your URL path to operate on a collection of objects, while resource_key is another path component for you to interact with a specific instance. Read some raw API design would be helpful for you to understand it.